# Accessing IFrame and Elements

Tags: javascript, iframe

needs some advice in accessing the IFrame using pure Javascript.

Context:
I have a JS script "A.JS" that contains a function "Func1". In the page, this function is called right before the IFrame as seen below

```
<script> A.Func1();</script>

<iframe src='xyz.com' title='Hello' type='portlet.iframe' > </iframe>
```

Please note that this IFrame is randomly generated, so I do not know its ID and Name at run time. Therefore the only way I can access it is by getting a handle on an array of IFrames and loop through each of them until I identify the correct one by its Title.

Also note that the JS function call is before/above the IFrame.

Now in my function `Func1()`, my codes are as follows. I tried to get a handle on the Correct IFrame but all the methods below are returning me Array of 0 length. I am pausing and seeing this in chrome version 29. Actually, the last array `iframeNodesAll4` are showing "Windows" as value!

```
var iframeNodesAll1 = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var iframeNodesAll2 = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var iframeNodesAll3 = window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var iframeNodesAll4 = window.frames;
```

So what am I missing here? Is it because the script is being called/loaded before the IFrame?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot get a reference to an element that does not exist at the moment the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because the script is being called/loaded before the IFrame?

Yes, I believe that is your problem, try moving the function call to after the iframe, and see what happens

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can wait until the page has loaded to run the function:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  A.func1();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Simon, oh no, if that's true that will be my worst nightmare. Is there any way that the Javascript A.Func1() can still access the IFrame and HTML elements below it? I am making customization to an existing application and doing it directly in the A.Func1() is the least invasive way. Thanks

Comment: The other option is to wait until the page has loaded, I'll edit my answer with that method.